# AngularJS animate not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Check this code: http://jsfiddle.net/j7C5B/

This is the html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div class="searchContainer" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li class="advSearchRow" ng-show="advSearch">
            <div class="todayButton">Today</div>
            <div class="tomorrowButton">Tomorrow</div>
            <div class="calendarButton">?</div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="advSearchButton" ng-click="display()">Advance Search</div></li>         
    </ul>    
</div>
```

It works perfectly with Chrome and Safari but it has a weird behavior in Firefox, anyone has an idea what is wrong with it? I have been trying to only leave height, line-height and different changes with no result yet. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: It's very different from what I thought, and is rather simple. Firefox requires `line-height` to have a unit, while Webkit browsers accept unit-less value and interpret as `em`. To fix it you just have to add `em` to the transition (or `px`, doesn't matter since it is 0, but there must be one unit). See http://jsfiddle.net/78rvg/

```
.advSearchRow.ng-hide
{
    line-height: 0em;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

---

The thing is: Your code assumes that the height of the buttons (`.todayButton`, `.tomorrorButton`...) to be the height of their container (`.advSearchRow`); which is not true in the case of floating elements (that's why we need clearfix).

You can fix this by specify the assumption explicitly for the buttons:

```
.advSearchRow > div { height: 100% }
```

or use `overflow: hidden`:

```
.advSearchRow { overflow: hidden }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't work as in Chrome. If you try it you will realize that after you hide the row the text goes to to the top of the row. So it is almost done! I will keep trying to get it done, this is getting me crazy, hehe. Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: Have you figured it out? Do you know what I mean? I am still not able to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy lately. The actual problem is far from what I thought and the fix is rather simple. See the updated answer :D

Comment: OMG, you are my angel. It is weird tho, before posting I tried with line-height: 0; and it wasn't working, (if I use 0 without em or px is still doesn't work and now I know why!!) so that's why I posted here. Thanks tungd!